# Replace string after at with another string

Tags: c#, c#-5.0

I have two strings.

First string:

```
"31882757623"<sip:+31882757623@asklync.nl;user=phone>;epid=5440626C04;tag=daa784a738
```

Second string:

```
vandrielfinance.nl
```

I want to replace asklync.nl to vandrielfinance.nl   in the first string after the `@` with the second string (`vandrielfinance.nl`). Everything else will stay the same.

So the new string will be:

```
"31882757623"<sip:+31882757623@vandrielfinance.nl;user=phone>;epid=5440626C04;tag=daa784a738
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
static string ReplaceSuffix(string orginal, string newString)
{
    string TobeObserved = "@";
    orginal = "\"31882757623\"<sip:+31882757623@asklync.nl;user=phone>;epid=5440626C04;tag=daa784a738";
    string second = "vandrielfinance.nl";
    string pattern = second.Substring(0, second.LastIndexOf("@") + 1);
    string code = orginal.Substring(orginal.IndexOf(TobeObserved) + TobeObserved.Length);

    //newString = Regex.Replace(code,second, pattern);
    newString = Regex.Replace(second, orginal, pattern);
    string hallo = orginal.Replace(newString, second);

    Console.Write("Original String: {0}", orginal);
    Console.Write("\nReplacement String: \n{0}", newString);

    Console.WriteLine("\n" + code);

    return newString;
}
```

Comment: split on the @, concat the first to the second

Comment: Thanks eddie, but what exactly do you mean? Can you show it me

Comment: If you change everything after the `@`, you end up with `"31882757623"<sip:+31882757623@vandrielfinance.nl`, *without* the `;user=phone>;epid=5440626C04;tag=daa784a738`. So you don't want to change everything after the `@`, but what *do* you want to do?

Comment: It should be clearer now that I fixed how SO was rendering the samples.

Comment: This is the original string: "31882757623"<sip:+31882757623@asklync.nl;user=phone>;epid=5440626C04;tag=daa784a738. so change asklync.nl to vandrielfinance.nl

Comment: @Nielshoi Yes, but what is the logic for determining that the rest should not be changed? That's something you should be able to express. It's something you'll *need* to be able to express if you have any hopes of the computer actually doing what you want. :)

Comment: I just want to replace asklync.nl to vandrielfinance.nl

Comment: `string.Replace`? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Then why not simply write `yourstring.Replace("asklync.nl", "vandrielfinance.nl")`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not really a fan a string.Split(), but it made for quick work in this case:

```
static string ReplaceSuffix(string orginal, string newString)
{
    var segments = original.Split(";".ToCharArray());
    var segments2 = segments[0].Split("@".ToCharArray());
    segments2[1] = newString;
    segments[0] = string.Join("@", segments2);
    var result = string.Join(";", segments);

    Console.WriteLine("Original String:\n{0}\nReplacement String:\n{1}, original, result);

    return result;
}
```

If the original domain will really always be `asklync.nl`, you may even be able to just do this:

```
static string ReplaceSuffix(string orginal)
{
    var oldDomain = "asklync.nl";
    var newDomain = "vandrielfinance.nl";
    var result = original.Replace(oldDomain, newDomain);

    Console.WriteLine("Original String:\n{0}\nReplacement String:\n{1}, original, result);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: It makes some assumptions that may or may not be correct, though. Personally, I'd rather see the OP more precisely state the valid forms of input strings first.

Comment: That's exactly why I don't normally want to use it :) I figured I could put as much work into my answer as the OP put into the question.

Comment: Thank you Joel, but I get some errors: Error 3 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'

Comment: Should run now. I forgot that the split() method wanted an array.

Answer (score 2):

why not string.Replace?

```
string s = "\"31882757623\"<sip:+31882757623@asklync.nl;user=phone>;epid=5440626C04;tag=daa784a738";
            string t = "vandrielfinance.nl";
            string u = s.Replace("asklync.nl", t);
            Console.WriteLine(u);
```

Comment: Agreed! Though you'll need to find the string of `"vandrielfinance.nl"` in order to do so.

Comment: you mean "asklync.nl"?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
        var orginal = "\"31882757623\"<sip:+31882757623@asklync.nl;user=phone>;epid=5440626C04;tag=daa784a738";
        string second = "vandrielfinance.nl";
        var returnValue = string.Empty;

        var split = orginal.Split('@');
        if (split.Length > 0)
        {
            var findFirstSemi = split[1].IndexOf(";");
            var restOfString = split[1].Substring(findFirstSemi, split[1].Length - findFirstSemi);

            returnValue = split[0] + "@" + second + restOfString;
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Original String:");
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", orginal);
        Console.WriteLine("Replacement String:");
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", returnValue);

        //return returnValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a huge fan of RegEx or string.Split, especially when a string function already exists to replace a portion of a string.

```
    string orginal  = "\"31882757623\"<sip:+31882757623@asklync.nl;user=phone>;epid=5440626C04;tag=daa784a738";
    string second  = "vandrielfinance.nl";
    int start = orginal .IndexOf("@");
    int end = orginal .IndexOf(";", start);
    string newString = orginal .Replace(orginal.Substring(start, end-start), second );
    Console.WriteLine(orginal );
    Console.WriteLine(newString);
```